# Always save HAProxy server state before stop

Tags: haproxy, systemd

We sometimes disable specific servers in HAProxy (running on RedHat 7, but compiled locally because 1.8 is not available from RedHat) using an admin socket and we want the state to be maintained if the server is restarted. We set HAProxy to load its state from a file with [`server-state-file`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#server-state-file), but we need to remember to save the state file every time we make a change. Is there a good way to make sure the state is saved every time the server stops?
If systemd had `ExecPreStop=`, we could include it from a file in `/etc/systemd/system` without modifying the distributed unit file, but systemd developers said they don't see the need for that directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up creating a "fake" service with just a stop action that depends on `haproxy.service` and therefor will have its `ExecStop` run before HAProxy is stopped.

haproxy-state.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Save HAProxy State Before Service Stop
After=haproxy.service
Requires=haproxy.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/socat /run/haproxy/control.socket - <<< \"show servers state\" > /var/lib/haproxy/last_state"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target haproxy.service
```

It needs to be **after** `haproxy.service` so it will stop **before**.
It needs to be `WantedBy` so that it will always be started any time HAProxy is running.

This isn't perfect because the state could change if there is a long pause before systemd stops the next service, but that is a risk we will take.

Comment: After 4 years, is this still your working solution? Looking for options myself.

Comment: @edmz It isn't perfect, but it does work. The state file is sensitive to the order of the entries, so sometimes when we modify the main config, we also need to fix up the state, but generally it works.

Answer (score -1):

You may consider to disable all the available `frontend` and `listen` sections before exporting its state. Something like running the following bash line (for each section): `echo 'disable frontend https_frontend' | socat /run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio`.

It can also be done by having a specific acl considered by all the `frontend` and `listen` sections. That will allow you to logically enable/disable them by running one single command like: `add acl ...' | socat /run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio` and `del acl ...' | socat /run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio`, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. This does not answer the question - the whole point of the question is how to save the state when the service stops, not how to change the state.