# Haproxy - stop traffic to node under maintenance

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

We've 2 active hosts for load balancing using haproxy. Haproxy is running on both the hosts. Due to maintenance we need to stop services on Host 1. During the maintenance window we want haproxy instance to stop sending traffic to host 1 and send all requests to Host 2.

**Purpose:** No outage during server maintenance.

**Current behaviour:** When service goes down on Host 1. Traffic is still sent to both Host 1 and 2. Since the backend services are down on Host 1, request times out and it is then Haproxy stops sending requests to Host 1. After the event of first failure all traffic if being sent to Host 2 and processed normally.

Is there a way to avoid losing this 1 transaction ( the first failure on Host 1) ? I read about enabling and disabling backend servers using socket file which needs socat or netcat. Haven't tested it but looking solution with haproxy configuration to resolve this.

### Backend definition in haproxy config

```
backend myBackend
   balance leastconn
   option httpchk HEAD /
   default-server inter 5s fastinter 1s downinter 10s fall 2 rise 2
   timeout server 20s
   server s1 ActiveHost1:port check  maxconn 10
   server s2 ActiveHost2:port check  maxconn 10
   server s3 standByHost1:port check  maxconn 10  backup
   server s4 standByHost1:port check  maxconn 10  backup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does commenting the line and reload haproxy would be ok for you?

`sed -i \"/server s1/c\\    #server s1 ActiveHost1:port check  maxconn 10\" /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg && sudo service haproxy reload`

Comment: off course updating the haproxy config to remove the balanced node under maintenance will work. However it won't be a simple sed replace in my case as the config contains multiple balanced node where each node have multiple backends and all  running on different port. Still I can write a script to do that. However I was looking for some out of box configuration in haproxy to do that. I read about http-check disable-on-404 , httpchk and check but not completely understand how they can be used to acheive this.

Comment: But this definitely is an option if I don't get any out of box solution :) .. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Haproxy's control socket supports sending a lot of different commands to control the behavior of the server. If you want to allow all existing connections to complete, but not send new connections, you can put the backend in DRAIN mode (make sure the control socket is enabled):

`echo "set server backend/serv state drain" | sudo socat stdio /run/haproxy/haproxysock`

You can set the backend to maintenance mode instead of DRAIN if you want to stop all traffic immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also decrease the time when a host is considered as DOWN by defining the service checking option.
According to the documentation, for example for a HTTP service:

- Define the service to check
- Define what to expect as result
- Define when a host is down - Here check every 3s. After 3 failed attemps, host is considered as DOWN. When 2 checks have the expected status, the host is considered as UP
- Define your hosts

`option httpchk GET /check
http-check expect status 200
default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
server srv1 10.0.0.1:80 check
server srv2 10.0.0.2:80 check`

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer pushed here: https://serverfault.com/a/1047892/608437

You may consider to disable all the available `frontend` and `listen` sections by running the following bash line (for each section): `echo 'disable frontend https_frontend' | socat /run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio`.

It can also be done by having a specific acl considered by all the `frontend` and `listen` sections. That will allow you to logically enable/disable them by running one single command like: `add acl ...' | socat /run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio` and `del acl ...' | socat /run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
So, you can do it with admin socket.

in haproxy.cfg, check if admin socket is enabled. if not add the below lines if needed. Haproxy supports 3 type of user - admin, operator and user.

========================
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/admin.sock mode 600 level admin
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/operator.sock mode 660 level operator user haproxy group haproxy
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/user.sock mode 660 level user uid 106 gid 112
========================

install socat and expect utility in the server.

========================
apt-get install expect socat rlwrap
yum install install expect socat rlwrap
========================

Bring the server in Maintenance, Drain or Ready

========================
[root@LB003 templates]# echo "set server be_beta-backend_shadow_om/IP_da-live-b000005 state drain" | socat stdio unix-connect:/var/lib/haproxy/admin_beta.sock

[root@LB003 templates]# echo "set server be_beta-backend_shadow_om/IP_da-live-b000005 state maint" | socat stdio unix-connect:/var/lib/haproxy/admin_beta.sock

[root@LB003 templates]# echo "set server be_beta-backend_shadow_om/IP_da-live-b000005 state ready" | socat stdio unix-connect:/var/lib/haproxy/admin_beta.sock
========================

Once beckend server is drained and put in maintenance you can bring down the server.
open the stats web uri and monitor the server. or check in command line.

========================
echo "show stat" | socat stdio unix-connect:/var/lib/haproxy/admin_beta.sock
========================

Happy Haproxying.
```